# A type of convergence of random variable

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables

Let $\{\xi_n\}_{n\geq1}:(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})\to(\mathbb{R^1},\text{Bor})$ be a sequence of random variable, and
$$\sum_{n\geq 1}E(|\xi_n-\xi|^p)<\infty.$$
Is there a name for this type of convergence? What are the connections between this type of convergence and $L^p$ convergence?

Comment: A sort of obvious comment: this is clearly stronger than Lp convergence, and furthermore, given an Lp convergent sequence, we can find a subsequence that converges in the sense that you write. Perhaps more useful is that, iirc, there are theorems that say that if a sequence converges in Lp, then there is a subsequence that converges pointwise ae, I wonder that your convergence is strong enough that you don't need to take a subsequence to get pointwise ae convergence.

Comment: The limit outside the sum does not make sense. If we have finiteness of this sum then $\sum |\xi_n-\xi|^{p} <\infty$ almost surely. Hence $\xi_n \to \xi$ almost surely but the stated property is much stronger than convergnce almost surely and in $L^{p}$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you. I have edited the post, there shouldn't be a limit.

Comment: This is called strong $L^p$ convergence. See the diagram in page 2 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.05806.pdf) summarizing the connections between this and other types of convergence.

Comment: @Michh Thank you so much!